# In java how to convert a string to date/time object for insertion into MS access

Tags: java, ms-access, jdbc-odbc

I need to do insertion into an MS access db. I'm using jdbc for doing it. I have time as a string "12:00:34" and need to insert it into MS access as a date/time object. How do I do it? I need to convert it into a 24hour time format

Comment: if you use parameterized queries you don't need to do this kind of conversion.  And you should be using parameterized queries in order to write more secure code.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to convert it to an SQL date here's an example [Java date to SQL](http://www.kodejava.org/examples/481.html)

Answer (score 0):

MS-Access stores dates as a double precision float, with 0 equal to 30 Dec 1899, 12 noon is stored as 0.5.

If you just have a time of 12:30 you need to store it in msaccess as 30 Dec 1899 12:30, for it to be interpreted as just a time.

If you needed to put this as a literal in Access SQL it would appear as #30/Dec/1899 12:30#

For example

```
INSERT INTO myTable (mydate) VALUES #30/Dec/1899 12:30#;
```

is a simple Access SQL Insert statement.